# Google Apps Script dynamically update Authorization Scopes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have deployed an Apps Script as WebApp which makes calls to the Google Drive API. The App can provide some basic functionality using only the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`. However, some users would like to have additional functionality which requires the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope. Is there a way to dynamically update the Authorization Scopes for this App when the user is explicitly requesting this?

Manifest File (appsscript.json):

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the detailed setting of your deployed Web Apps in your question?

Comment: Are you including the scopes in the manifest? When using Apps Script services the scopes are usually added automatically; so depending on the action and as long as the user authorizes the app, the user should be able to perform the things they want.

Comment: @Tanaike Do you mean the Manifest File? I have included it in my question. @ale13 I have included the `drive.metadata.readonly` scope. But if I also include `drive.readonly` or if I delete the `oauthScopes` entry from the file, the App will directly ask for both scopes. I would prefer to ask for `drive.readonly` only if the user wants this additional functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sadly, there is no way of doing this using Apps Script.**

However, depending on the user's preference, you may redirect the user to execute another script/web app which does the task which requires the more permissive scope.

You can also request a feature on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).